# Why can't I reverse strings by striding from 0 to their length by -1?

Tags: python, string, reverse

In Python, I know I can reverse strings doing

```
'dfdfsdf'[::-1]
```

and that essentially makes it step backwards. However when I try to run this it won't work

```
string = 'dfdfsdf'
reversed = string[0:len(string):-1]
print(reversed)
```

I was just wondering doing this doesn't work; the format is [first:last:step], so I thought I could.

Comment: You can't go from zero to a positive number striding by `-1`

Comment: @khelwood That won't work. `-1` is still treated as the last character (not a number before `0`), so that returns an empty string.

Comment: @Surya what exactly are you trying to do with reversed?

Comment: @SierraMountainTech Nothing. I program mostly in Java and just started learning Python. I was just wondering doing this doesn't work. Because the format is [first:last:step] so I thought I could. Could you explain it a bit more?

Comment: @Surya what is it that you thought you could do? There is no context. Are you trying to specify a stopping point when reversing? They way you can do that is by making the `last` portion a negative number. something like `reversed = string[:((-1)*len(string)):-1]`

Comment: `string[len(string)-1:-len(string)-1:-1]` See my explanation in the duplicate

Comment: I think Chris_Rands answer on the linked question will best describe the behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because iteration in list works like this:

```
list[start_point:end_point:iteration]
```

so for your method you need to write:

```
reversed = string[len(string)-1:-len(string)-1:-1]
```

more explained in dupe link

or you can achive reserved list/string  using functions like this:

```
reversed = "".join(reversed(string))
```

Comment: Your last line should make it clear why you should avoid built-in names as variable names. You immediately shadow the class `reversed`, so the next call will fail: `reversed = "".join(reversed(string))`

Comment: Your explanation is wrong, `string[len(string):0:-1] == string[::-1]` is `False`, as I commented `string[len(string)-1:-len(string)-1:-1]` see the dupe

Comment: If I do that then why do I have to iterate back by -1? Shouldn't I just use 1 since its going backwards either way?

Comment: Yep, i explained wrong. Because if you iterate to 0, it will exclude 0 index. Thanks for pointing it Chris.